# Write SQL Query by Month

Tags: sql, excel

For the Excel `table` below, how do I add up the `Orders` column by `month`?  I wrote the following query, but I would have to change the query for each subsequent month, which seems like a very manual process.  Thanks in advance.

Update:

Hedging my answer by providing 2 that are not incorrect, but very manual for monthly calculation (need to tweak the query for each subsequent month or year).

**Part 1 - Calculates 1 number for Total:**

```
SELECT SUM(orders)
FROM table
```

**Part 2 - Calculates 1 number for each month:**

```
SELECT SUM(orders)
FROM table
WHERE summary_date BETWEEN #01/01/2015# AND #01/31/2015#;
```

[image]

Comment: Why not create a pivot table instead? That inherently knows how to roll up by month.

Comment: Ya I think there're other possibilities, but I was asked to do it in SQL with a SQL query.

Comment: With SQL you'd use the MONTH() function and the GROUP BY().

Comment: Thanks @Duston - ya that's the way.  How would that look, and would I need to define any variable using As?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data:

```
sellDate    qty
2021-01-15  1
2021-01-21  2
2021-02-21  2
2021-02-01  29
2021-01-15  1
2021-01-15  1
2021-01-15  1
2020-02-01  29
2021-01-15  1
```

The query

```
select year(selldate), month(selldate) as month, count(selldate) as qty, sum(qty) as amt
from [wrox].[dbo].[Test]
where selldate is not null
group by year(selldate), month(selldate)
```

The results

```
year    month   qty amt
2021    1       6   7
2020    2       1   29
2021    2       2   31
```

You can concatenate the year and month if you don't want them in separate columns.  But that looks like what you were asking for.

BTW, this is MS SQL 2014.